# NSPersistentUIManager - deflate

Tags: cocoa, osx-lion, instruments

I was doing a time profiling at startup for my mac app and I don't remember seeing this class being called in snow leopard, but can't be sure. 
Does anyone know what is it for?
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's Lions new feature for saving and restoring the window states like position, etc. It "persists" the "UI" by compressing (aka deflate) and later restores it by "inflating" them.